# Is this correct

Tags: discussion

Over the post few weeks there have been several "Is this correct?" questions.

It seems like this is a weird fit for SE, but on the general meta (based on Stackoverflow context) [they seem to encourage such questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91671/is-an-is-this-correct-question-appropriate-for-stackoverflow). So even though such questions will tipically not get an affirmative answer ("Yes." is only 4 characters) such questions are on-topic.

(I think there is also some reluctance to close due to the OP having demonstrated effort.)

Is what I wrote above correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

To cover the required answer-length threshold, confirmation is a useful tool in the educational process. The issue is "does it add valuable content to the site?"

If the answer is "No", providing guidance towards the "Yes" conforms with the purpose of the site, and also, stays there for future wanderers.

If the answer is "Yes", an extra burden is placed on those who answer to make the thread valuable -for example by indicating any redundant steps the OP took, or suggest an alternative way, or show how it is a special case of some more general methodology.

Comment: I was trying to decide what kind of answer to write, but let me instead say that I think Alecos' answer captures my sentiment pretty well.